# 2 mesh circuit giving me trouble. (steady-stade, mesh current method, dependent current source)

Tags: current-measurement, steady-state

[image]
[image]

The task is to find **`Ic`** in phasor form. 
The circuit is in steady sinusoidal state.

I used mesh current analysis and I got to that:

[image]

I have no idea how to keep going from there. Also the answer has been given as **Ic = 0,5 - j0,5**

Sorry if I don't use the terminology correctly. I can explain if needed.

Comment: Differentiation transforms to multiplying by \$j\omega\$, so the current source is \$0.5j\omega I_b=jI_b\$

Comment: @Chu so this means that the equivelant of differentiation on the time field(if my terminology is correct) is multiplying by jω in the frequency field.( im gonna delete the comment . just to check if i get it right)

Comment: Yes. In Laplace, multiplying a variable by s is differentiation and \$s\rightarrow j\omega\$. Are you sure that 0.5 - j0.5 is correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Cant upvote anything though.Got my answer

Comment: Upvoting isn't an issue.